# Laravel Carbon, retrieve today's date with weekday?

Tags: laravel, datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am using carbon to compare 2 dates with today's date, however I also have another field in a database called weekday which contains values like:

'MO'
'TU'
'WE'

So I don't only want to search and output by dates but also search by a weekday so:

```
public function show($id)
{   
    $today = Carbon::now();
    $weekday = //whatever carbon or something else has to retrieve today's day
    $event = Event::with('businesses')
       ->where('startdate', '<', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
       ->where('endate', '>', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
       //or where ('weekday') = $weekday?
       ->get();
    return view('events.showEvent', compact('event'));
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'm not sure that Carbon has such formatting, but what you could do is get the wekkday from a map of days and the current week day constant:

```
$weekMap = [
    0 => 'SU',
    1 => 'MO',
    2 => 'TU',
    3 => 'WE',
    4 => 'TH',
    5 => 'FR',
    6 => 'SA',
];
$dayOfTheWeek = Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek;
$weekday = $weekMap[$dayOfTheWeek];
```

Comment: is 0 ALWAYS sunday??? cause not everyones week starts with sunday

Comment: ```Carbon::now()->dayOfWeekIso``` should return as ```1=>monday ``` ```7=>sunday```

Comment: "I'm not sure that Carbon has such formatting" => `Carbon::now()->englishDayOfWeek` will return the week days as Sunday or Monday

Comment: Be aware that Carbon's day numbering is different to [MySQL's `WEEKDAY` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday), which uses Monday = 0, Sunday = 6.

Answer (score 25):

If you're in an English-speaking locale, you can get that short weekday format by doing some processing on Carbon's `l` format, which returns weekday names:

```
strtoupper(substr($today->format('l'), 0, 2)); // Returns 'MO', 'TU', etc
```

It can be even shorter if you have access to Carbon 2 (available on 2018-08-31):

```
strtoupper($today->isoFormat('dd'));
```

Comment: this answer is far better

Answer (score 5):

### 2022 Update

Carbon seems to have a lot more methods to offer now.
For this scenario something as simple as this will work:

```php
strtoupper(Carbon::now()->minDayName);
```

If you are not in an englis locale you can add `locale('en')` to it.
But there are also a lot more things you can make use of.
Check out the getters section at the [docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for more info.

```php
$dt = Carbon::now();

// dayOfWeek returns a number between 0 (sunday) and 6 (saturday)
var_dump($dt->dayOfWeek);                                  // int(5)
// dayOfWeekIso returns a number between 1 (monday) and 7 (sunday)
var_dump($dt->dayOfWeekIso);                               // int(5)
var_dump($dt->englishDayOfWeek);                           // string(6) "Friday"
var_dump($dt->shortEnglishDayOfWeek);                      // string(3) "Fri"
var_dump($dt->locale('de')->dayName);                      // string(7) "Freitag"
var_dump($dt->locale('de')->shortDayName);                 // string(3) "Fr."
var_dump($dt->locale('de')->minDayName);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works perfect

```
    Carbon::parse($invoice->date)->format('l d M Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dayOfWeek = Carbon::parse($delivery->delivery_date)->dayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Please add some more details on how this answers the question and how this differs from existing answers. Code-only answers are not the most useful ones.

Answer (score -2):

$weekday = Carbon::parse($today)->format('1');